# Access property values of properties values in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is what my data looks like...

```
var data = [ 
    {
        name: 'Bart',
        grade: 4,
        teacher: 'Krabappel',
        record: ['Set fire to skinner','Threw poop at Milhouse'],
        friends: [
                {
                    name: 'Milhouse',
                    grade: 4,
                    teacher: 'Krabappel',
                    record: ['Sang songs', 'Reads loudly'],
                    friends: 
                            { 
                                name: 'Martin',
                                grade: 4,
                                teacher: 'Krabappel',
                                record: 'NONE',
                                friends: 'NONE'
                            }

                },
                {
                    name: 'Nelson',
                    grade: 4,
                    teacher: 'Krabappel',
                    record: ['Burnt classroom','Stole skinners car','Beat up Milhouse'],
                    friends: 'NONE'
                }
            ]
    }
    //{name: 'Lisa'}, 
    //{name: 'Maggie'} 
];
```

I'm trying to grab ALL instances of friends and log it.

```
function getFriends(data) {
    data.map(function (n) {
        var frands = n.friends; // works!
        var fof = frands.friends; // does not work
        console.log(frands);
        console.log(fof); 
    });
}

getFriends(data);
```

How would I get all instances of friends including friends-of-friends?

Comment: This type of data structure looks a bit verbose, if not difficult to traverse. What happens if Lisa and Maggie are also friends with Milhouse - is all that data duplicated? Triplicated?

Comment: Traverse? (Good call btw)

Comment: Traverse = picking through the data. Due to the structure, it's difficult to pull all the friends out, since they can be so deeply nested. It might be worth having two objects to hold this info: `people` and `relationships`, where `people` is an array that holds the metadata about each person (name, grade, etc), but not the `friends` attribute, but add an `id` though to each `person`. Then in `relationships` we have a structure like `[{<personId>: [personId, personId]}, {<personId>: [<personId, personId]}`, where we just attach Bart all all his friends ids, and etc.

Comment: @lux makes sense. I'm not entirely sure the data is manipulable. If i were building the data myself then sure, i'd assign each Person object these values.

Comment: @lux does the `.map()` method create a new array effectively? I thought I'd be able to essentially create a new array for both friends... and then the nested friends-of-friends.

Comment: This is a typical recursive work but as @Modelesq has already pointed out with this data structure you will end with a friends array most possibly including redundant data. Also you should take precautions not to get trapped in an infinite loop. (like friends turn back to each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because more array is exist on it ,so use for loop will be ok

```
function getFriends(data) {
    data.map(function (n) {
        var frands = n.friends; // works!
        for(var i =0;i <frands.length;i++){
        var fof = frands[i].friends; 
        console.log(fof); 
        }

        console.log(frands);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This calls for some recursion.

```
var allFriends = []; //global to store unique friend objects

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].friends != null){
        getAll(data[i].friends);
    }
}

function found(friend){
   for(var i = 0; i < allFriends.length; i++){
      if(allFriends[i].name == friend.name){
        return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}

function getAll(friends){
   if(friends != null){
       for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++){
          if(!found(friends[i])){
             var friendcopy = friends[i];
             if(friendcopy.friends != null){
                delete friendcopy.friends;
                 getAll(friends[i].friends);
             }
             allFriends.push(friendcopy);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

This will store all the unique friends found in the data array.  The first function checks if the friend is already inside of the global variable `allFriends` and if not then the recursive function will continue to scan indefinitely until all data elements are exhausted.  When the recursion is complete, allFriends should contain all friend objects.

Although this type of function could become problematic if there is a very large amount of items in `data`

Comment: Hmm it appears as though Milhouse is being duplicated and Martin isn't included. Is it possible that javascript can't access arrays that deeply nested?

Comment: @Modelesq it must be the line that deletes the friends object from friendscopy.  i threw that in to keep mem usage low.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. While your answer makes sense to me, it doesn't 100% solve my issue/question (mainly regarding the duplication issue).